# How to perform arithmetic functions on fields in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have some data in elastic search. I use Kibana to visualize that data. Now, I have three fields:

```
- dataThroughput.totalPackets 
- dataThroughput.receivedPackets
- dataThroughput.lostPackets
```

I want to write a query where I would all the results where totalPpackets != C - lostPackets.
(C is a constant that can change).

I tried the following query:

```
dataThroughput.totalPackets.value != 20 - dataThroughput.lostPackets.value
```

But I didn't get the results.

Is my query correct?

Comment: Try using the correct format `doc['dataThroughput.totalPackets'].value`

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to achieve this:

1. I think that the simplest option would be to use **Scripted Fields**:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/scripted-fields.html

which allows you to reference any single value numeric field like this:

> doc['field_name'].value

2. other options are **Bucket Script Aggregation** :
   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html
3. And one more option is to use **timelion math**:
   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/timelion-math.html